# Python Script to grab bitcoin price and send by sms

Tags: python-3.x, twilio-api

guys, I am trying to grab bitcoin price and send by SMS to my number. please tell me how can I send the result via SMS after every 10 minutes. I am using twilio API.

```
import requests
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

def btc():
    r=requests.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
    btc= r.json()['bpi']['USD']['rate']
    print('The Current Bitcoin Price: ' + btc + ' Usd')

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(btc, 'interval', seconds = 3)
scheduler.start()
```